# How to disable Rails ActionCable WebSocket channel for other Rails app in local env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm working on two different Rails apps. On App 1, I created a channel to broadcast changes called "ProductsChannel". I later shut down the server for App 1, and spun up the server for App 2 which I hadn't worked on in a couple days. But now it's trying to connect to my "ProductsChannel" from App 1. It can't find it so it tells me repeatably that it can't find the channel. Logs are below.

How do I stop App 2 from trying to use WebSockets? I've never added any channels to App 2 so not sure how it got pulled into this.

```
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2023-09-21 14:57:20 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Pluck (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2023-09-21 14:57:20 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2023-09-21 14:57:20 +0200
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2023-09-21 14:57:20 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2023-09-21 14:57:20 +0200
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2023-09-21 14:57:20 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Subscription class not found: "ProductsChannel"
Subscription class not found: "ProductsChannel"
Subscription class not found: "ProductsChannel"
...
```

Both apps are on Rails 7.

I've made sure App 1's server is not running. I've tried shutting down App 2 and restarting.

I suspect a laptop reboot might solve it, but I shouldn't have to reboot my whole machine every time I switch apps.

Comment: May be you have opened browser tabs with app1? BTW why don't run apps on different ports?

Comment: Yes, turns out I did have an open browser tab with app 1. Closing that resolved the issue. Thanks. It's a good idea running on different ports. I hadn't bothered because one app is just following along with a tutorial and the other is something I'm actually building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the logs of enabled application contain requests to the websockets endpoint and even contain records that it was not possible to find channel of disabled application — it means some client still has connection to your server and send these requests

In this regard, the first thought is an open browser tab that was subscribed to the websocket channel on the same port as the current backend

To exclude this behavior, you can either close such tabs or use different ports for different applications

Answer (score 0):

Credit to mechnikov in the comments for pointing out my noob error. I had a browser tab open with App 1. Closing this tab resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).